# Gerar lista dinamicamente com Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Tenho uma API que usa o dynamic do DotNet para gerar os boletos. A documentação é a seguinte:

```
dynamic endpoints = new Endpoints("client_id", "client_secret", true);

var body = new
{
items = new[] {
    new {
        name = "Primeiro item da descrição",
        value = 1000,
        amount = 1
    },
    new {
        name = "Segundo item da descrição",
        value = 1000,
        amount = 1
        },
    },
};

var response = endpoints.CreateCharge(null, body);
```

Esta é minha query que eu preciso para preencher os itens no corpo:

```
var itensCobranca = from p in db.DetalhesCobrancas
                where p.CobrancaId == 2
                select p;

    foreach(var item in itensCobranca)
    {
        name = item.Descricao;
        amount = item.Qtde;
        value = item.valor;
    }
```

O problema é que como se trata de itens dinâmicos não posso gerar os itens no corpo com Linq. Tentei montar a body, e depois os itens através do **String.Format**(grosseria!)
Como posso fazer essa implementação e gerar cada item puxando do banco?

**EDIT**

Segue o bloco

```
gerencianetDataContext db = new gerencianetDataContext();
        var cobrancas = (from p in db.DetalhesCobrancas
                         where p.CobrancaId == 2
                         select p).ToList();
        foreach (var item in cobrancas)
        {
            string itens = String.Format("new {{name = \"{0}\",value = {1},amount = 1}},", item.Descricao, item.IntValor);

            Literal.Text += itens;
        }

        string items = Literal.Text;//define string puro dos itens
        //agora o corpo

        //tentando transformar em objeto
        List<object> Obj1AsObjects = items.Cast<object>().ToList();

        //gerando o boleto
        dynamic endpoints = new Endpoints("Client_Id", "Client_Secret", true);
        var body = new
        {
            items = new[]{
                Obj1AsObjects
            }
        };

        var response = endpoints.CreateCharge(null, body);
```

Comment: Por que nao trabalha com um ViewModel amigo?

Comment: Pra que usar `dynamic`? Vejo zero razões para isto. Põe o tipo `EndPoints` e resolva o problema (se for esse, eu acho que até é outro, a pergunta diz que tem problema, mas não é clara quanto a isso.).

Comment: Maniero é que esse Endpoint é um SDK de terceiro para gerar boletos na API. Eu precisava implementar um método para gerar os itens da body em Linq, que geram tudo em runtime

Comment: Vitor, esse é um projeto WebForms, realmente seria mais facil.

Comment: mas as propriedades do objeto anônimo para montar o corpo do boleto não serão sempre name, amount e value? Acredito que vc poderia sim gerar o corpo na consulta Linq

Comment: Sim, eu tento, mas ele atira essa exceção: Detalhes da Exceção: Gerencianet.SDK.GnException: {
 "property": "/items/0",
 "message": "Tipo inválido: array (esperado object)."
}

Comment: parece que erro está na atribuição dos itens... cada item espera um objeto (name, amount e value) mas vc está atribuindo um array (provavelmente o array de itens que vc montou) mostre a parte do código que vc está montando o objeto `body` e principalmente o preenchimento da propriedade `items`.

Comment: vou editar  a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Tente esta alteração (completo):

```
gerencianetDataContext db = new gerencianetDataContext();
var cobrancas = (from p in db.DetalhesCobrancas
                 where p.CobrancaId == 2
                 select new {
                     name = p.Descricao,
                     value = p.ItemValor,
                     amount = 1
                 });

//gerando o boleto
dynamic endpoints = new Endpoints("Client_Id", "Client_Secret", true);
var body = new
{
    items = cobrancas.ToArray()
};

var response = endpoints.CreateCharge(null, body);
```

Comment: ele mudou o erro, agora foi para string {
 "property": "/items/0",
 "message": "Tipo inválido: string (esperado object)."
}

Comment: então vai ter que mudar o código do começo, no Linq faça no select `select new { name=p.Descricao, amount=1, value=p.ItemValor}` e passe cobrancas.ToArray() na propriedade `items` no `body`

Comment: JMSlasher, ele agora diz que esta em string novamente. Eu vejo que preciso converter ele em objeto    {
 "property": "/items/0",
 "message": "Tipo inválido: string (esperado object)."
}

Comment: estranho, pq `cobrancas` agora deveria retornar objetos (anônimos com as propriedades name, value e amount) e não string.

Comment: Eu acho que estou quase la. Estou tentando trazer pro meu problema a primeira resposta desta pergunta respondida aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898731/creating-a-json-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: JMSlasher, obrigado, essa implementação deu certo !!!